# Is this a typo in Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra 2e?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

On page 203 on the part about characterizing triangulability it looks like there's a typo in the indicies they sum over on eqn (6-12).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Hoffman and Kunze. The $j$th column of the matrix should be the coefficients of $T\alpha_j$ with respect to the ordered basis $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_j \}$.

Comment: Agree with this.  +1